# Apache2 GeoIP / mod_geoip2 custom error page

Tags: apache, geoip

Whenever an ip is blocked by mod_geoip2 on apache, it shows a "Forbidden /" error. The geo ip blocking works fine, but is there any possibility to display a custom error page or message when the ip is blocked?

I took a look ad maxminds documentation but there is nothing mentioned. Maybe someone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example :

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !(US|GB|CA)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error_page.html [NC,L]
```

Hope above rules answers your question

Comment: Wont't it be blocked it by itself?

Comment: The above example checks the IP and redirects the request to error_page.html in case the IP does not belong to US,GB and CA. Can you let me know the rule that you are using, if it is other than the mentioned above ?

Comment: i am using this example in my vhost config: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2#Allowing_clients_based_on_country-19 (Allowing clients based on country) I do not use .htaccess for blocking

Comment: Check this : http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2 and go to section "Redirecting a client based on country". You redirect request to any page based on the country

Comment: yes but this only works in htaccess i think. and if i do it with htaccess i have to place htaccess in every folder of my app. if i have it in my vhost config, it "secures" my whole vhost. is it not possible to include it in vhost? or can i just use this code in my vhost too?

Comment: You can add it in your vhost setting also, as you do other rewrite rules. Just put the rules inside your vhost and, make sure to add "GeoIPEnable On" and "GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat" directives before the rule. If you need help , let me know your vhost I'll add the rules in it.